# Use jQuery between two HTML pages over a local network

Tags: html, jquery, lan

I have two PC's that are connected over a LAN.

One of the PC's I'm using as a master server with XAMPP installed.

Is it possible to communicate simple jQuery between two html pages on two different PCs?

```
  $(".button").click(function() {
    //change div colour on other html page
    $(".div").css("background", "red");
  })
```

...something as simple as that.

Thanks

Comment: Probably not, because your pages is not receiving any requests and do not know anything about the states of each other. You need to use websocket to create realtime bidirectional communication. Try https://socket.io/

Comment: Ok, thanks - I'll give that a go

Comment: I got the chat demo working on socket.io - but if I try and reference the socket & jquery files locally it breaks - this need to be an offline solution - any ideas?